# How to resolve findIndex is not a function error in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular app, I am storing an array of `Message` objects within a `Conversation` object.

I was able to add a new `Message` to a hard-coded `Conversation` with the below code:

```
private _conversations = new BehaviorSubject<Conversation[]>([]);

get conversations() {
    return this._conversations.asObservable();
}

addMessageToConversation(conversationId: string, message: string) {
    return this.conversations.pipe(
      take(1),
      tap(conversations => {
        const updatedConversationIndex = conversations.findIndex(convo => convo.id === conversationId);
        const updatedConversations = [...conversations];
        const convoToUpdate = updatedConversations[updatedConversationIndex]; 
        convoToUpdate.messages.push(
          new Message(
            Math.random().toString(),
            message,
          )
        );
        this._conversations.next(updatedConversations);
      })
    );
  }
```

I made the below changes to this method so that I could update the object in a Firebase DB:

```
addMessageToConversation(conversationId: string, message: string) {
    let updatedConversations: Conversation[];
    return this.conversations.pipe(
      take(1), switchMap(conversations => {
        console.log(conversations);
        const updatedConversationIndex = conversations.findIndex(convo => convo.id === conversationId);
        updatedConversations = [...conversations];
        const convoToUpdate = updatedConversations[updatedConversationIndex];
        convoToUpdate.messages.push(
          new Message(
            Math.random().toString(),
            message,
          )
        );
        return this.http.put(
          `myUrl/conversations/${conversationId}.json`,
          { ...convoToUpdate, id: null }
        );
      }), tap(() => {
        this._conversations.next(updatedConversations);
      })
    );
  }
```

But now when I call this method, I get this console error:

> conversations.findIndex is not a function

This error is in relation to this line of code:

`const updatedConversationIndex = conversations.findIndex(convo => convo.id === conversationId);`

Also, when I `console.log(conversations)` inside `switchMap`, this is logged:

> {id: "-M52u0Fwdt5a9xE0wwCk", userId: "user3", mechanicId: "user2",
>   messages: Array(1)}

Can someone please tell me why this is happening, & what changes are required to get it working?

Comment: `findIndex` works for array only, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that `conversations` is an array, you can just set the type of it to `any`

```
...
switchMap((conversations: any) => {
     const updatedConversationIndex = conversations.findIndex(convo => convo.id === conversationId);
     updatedConversations = [...conversations];
...
```

Or even better create a type for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this code gives me the same error. I am showing what `conversations` is in my question aboce now

Comment: So that is an object, not an array. Maybe you want to use `findIndex` on the `messages`?

Comment: Yep, so what I want do here is add / push a new `Message` to the `Message` array inside `Conversation`

Comment: You can directly use `conversations.messages` because you have already the the only one via `take(1)`. No more filtering is needed

Comment: OK, I will try to get my code working based on this. Is it possible for you to show how it should be done above in your answer?

Comment: Just omit `findIndex` part, cause you don't have any array. But first look at your logic, maybe you need to have an array there and `take(1)` is not correct in this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211865/discussion-between-user9847788-and-suren-srapyan).